# RESTful query string convention for "value is present"

Tags: rest, url

Say we have a URL like:

```
http://example.org/resources/?property=1
```

This will return every `resource` where the value of `property` is `1`, pretty straightforward. But what if `property` is nullable, and we want to search for all `resources` with a non-null query string? I can think of a couple of ideas:

```
http://example.org/resources/?property
http://example.org/resources/?property=present
```

But the first one requires treating `""` as a special value (and distinguishing it from `http://example.org/resources/`, where `property` isn't even in the URL -- which isn't necessarily straightforward in some frameworks), and the second requires declaring and documenting that `present` is a special value, which goes against the general principle that good API URLs ought to be obvious and unsurprising. And what if `property` is a free-text field that can't have any reserved words? Is there a well-accepted way of doing this?

Comment: Why not... http://example.org/resources to return all resources?

Comment: Seems like meeting your criteria of allowing it to be a free text field, but also requiring it to be present for your framework handling, is kind of impossible. `?property=null` is least surprising to me though.

Comment: @Jason Of course `example.org/resources` to return all `resources`, but I don't want all `resources`, I just want the ones where `property` is set.

Comment: @Frug is it, though? That implies that by default you're only returning `resources` where `property` is non-null, rather than all `resources`. I think that would turn out to be surprising.